# Como obtener el value de un input e insertarlo en el maxLength con JS, actualmente lo obtengo con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hola necesito cambiar este codigo Jquery a JS, soy nuevo en esto aun no tengo el suficiente conocimiento

**ACTUALMENTE EL MAXLENGTH SE ESTABLECE POR EL NUMERO DE SELECT ELEGIDO (SOLO ESTA PERMITIDO INSERTAR LETRAS,  CUANDO SE ELIGE LA OPCION 1 DEBE ANEXAR 2 LETRAS )**

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uno").change(function () {
      var valor1 = $("#uno").val();
       var suma = valor1 ;
       console.log(suma);
      document.getElementById("text").maxLength = parseInt(valor1) + 1;
      document.getElementById("text").value = "";

    });
  });


  function soloLetras(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which,
      tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase(),
      letras = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz",
      // especiales = [8, 37, 39, 46],
      especiales = false,
      tecla_especial = false;

    for (var i in especiales) {
      if (key == especiales[i]) {
        tecla_especial = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (letras.indexOf(tecla) == -1 && !tecla_especial) {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <select class="single-option-selector" name="uno" data-option="option1" id="uno">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>

    </select>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" maxlength="1">
    <br>
```

Comment: Recuerda que para mejorar tus chances de que la comunidad te ayude debes intentar algo, posterior en tu pregunta agregar que llevas y que error(es) ha(s) obtenido. Aquí puedes leer [ask]

Comment: Como ya te han dicho, debes intentar algo y luego poner una pregunta cuando tengas la algún problema

Comment: Buenas! He revisado tu pregunta y tengo algunas recomendaciones que hacer. 1 - Lee [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/) para que entiendas por que tu pregunta podría no ser bien recibida y terminar cerrada y/o con votos negativos. 2 - Si llega a ser necesario subir código, procura que sea un [mcve](/help/minimal-reproducible-example), no olvides formatear el código usando [markdown](/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

Teniendo el Input y un Boton que cambia el maxlength dependiendo de ese Input (porque tu HTML no esta):

```
<input type="text" id="lengthinput" title="maxlength insert">
<button type="button" id="submitbutton" title="maxlength submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

Usando el evento onclick y alguna que otra validación cambiamos el tamaño máximo del input. La propiedad `type` del input la puse como `text` porque por algún motivo aunque cambie el `maxlength` de un input tipo `number` este me deja exceder esa cantidad, por eso hago las validaciones para asegurar que el valor del input es un número y no un texto o un campo vacío.

```
let input = document.getElementById("lengthinput")
let button = document.getElementById("submitbutton")
button.onclick = () => {
  if(input.value!=="" && !isNaN(input.value)) {
   input.setAttribute("maxlength",input.value) 
   input.value = "";
  } else alert("field is empty or incorrect!")
}
```

Comment: AHORITA COMPARTO EL HTML ESTA SENCILLO, LO QUIERO QUE SE EJECUTE EN TIEMPO REAL , SI SE CAMBIA EL NÚMERO DEL SELECT SE ACTUALIZE EL MAX-LENGTH